# Problems making a soap request

Tags: java, android, soap, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to make a request to a soap API, using ksoap2 library version 3.6.2.

The problem is that I'm getting the error message:

> "SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@338a49b".

My code looks like this:

```
String NAMESPACE = "x";
String METHOD_NAME = "x";
String SOAP_ACTION = "x";
String URL = "x";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

request.addProperty("userName", "x");
request.addProperty("Password", "x");

//request.addProperty("token","token","?");

Log.i("SOAP: ", request.toString());

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.implicitTypes = false;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


HttpsTransportSE aht = new HttpsTransportSE("x", 8900, "x", 50000);
aht.debug = true;

// make call
try {

    aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

    Log.i("RESP:", aht.responseDump.toString());
    Log.i("RESPONSE: ", result.toString());

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I think the problem could be that it takes one more property, the one I commented out in the code.

How can i add a property with an attribute? Like this: `<token Token="">`, because I think that is what I'm missing to get a response back.

I tested it with postman, it works great, but only when I have these 3 properties (userName, Password and token).

Comment: Then why did you comment it?

Comment: Because it did'nt work, I just wanted to show what i want to achieve.

I need that property "token" but i don't really know how to add an attribute to it with a value..

Comment: What error did you get with `request.addProperty("token","yourtoken");` uncommented?

Comment: `request.addProperty("token","yourtoken");` gives me `<token>yourtoken</token>`.

i need it to be `<token Token="?" />`

Comment: I need to create elements on my own or something, and send that to the soap request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `addAttribute` method to add attributes to properties.

Try this code,

```
request.addProperty("userName", "x");
request.addProperty("Password", "x");

SoapObject token = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "token");
token.addAttribute("Token", "your_token");
request.addSoapObject(token);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me! 

I was taking a look at the generated xml, I need to add a new xmlns url in the Envelope element, is that possible somehow? Thanks.

`<v:Envelope xmlns:n1="myownurlhere">`

Comment: I think you need to use `PropertyInfo` class with `setNamespace` method. Please post a new question for that. You can post the url of the question in the comments below. Please accept it this helped you. :)

Comment: Where is the addSoapObject() method? There is no method like this in ksoap2 library. Please acknowledge me :(